# Javascript - Break code execution

Tags: javascript, return, exit, execution

How can I stop a script from continue executing? Example:

```
var a = $(".divclass");

if(a.length == 0){ //If div doesn't exist
    //stop execution, exit, break or whatever
}

...
...
...
```

As you can see I'm not in a function, so `return` throws me error...

Comment: Can't you wrap this code with `function`?

Comment: I can, but is there a way I can "exit" without a `return`? That's my question, thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, **no way** in Javascript.

Comment: Wow, a simple `exit` like PHP would do the job.

Comment: Not in a clean way. you can throw something (a string for example): `throw "";` . Or surround your code in an anonymous function: `!function() { /* code */ return ; /* code */`

Comment: Yes, I knew the anonymous function way, but I don't really need a function, that's why I'm wondering how to exit without returning.

Comment: @RayonDabre I was comparing with PHP, obviously exit won't work. Btw, I'm the author of this question, just in case you didn't know.

Comment: @chumkiu `throw` in such case will result to error since that code isn't wrapped with `try..catch`. I don't think the OP wants this.

Comment: _a simple exit like PHP would do the job..._ Obviously Javascript is **not** PHP

Comment: If a function would provide the exact functionality you need, why do you insist that you "don't really need a function"? Wrapping your code in a function is a superior solution for many other reasons.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid, Ooh, I thought someone was suggestion you. There is no way you can achieve this in JavaScript.

Comment: @hindmost I didn't mean `exit` to be an answer. I just meant that the answer could be a simple `exit` like we can find in PHP if it was available in Javascript.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid, You can set a `flag` and can make conditions as per the value of the flag. `exit` sort of thing is not possible. I am just giving you other way around..

Comment: BTW `exit` in php caused more issues than solutions  (how many exit for debug have you pushed online?) :-)